# Change font on WordPress WYSIWYG editor

Tags: wordpress

I have the latest version of WordPress and have noticed on the WYSIWYG text editor there is no option to change the font and font size.

What can I do to include an option to change the font on the editor, is there some plugin available that does it?

Answer (score 0):

From first result on google:

http://www.lancelhoff.com/customizing-the-wordpress-wysiwyg-tinymce-visual-editor/

Take a look into `tiny_mce_confg.php`

```
$mce_buttons = apply_filters('mce_buttons', array('fontselect', 'fontsizeselect'))
```

These Buttons exist:

```
bold
italic
underline
strikethrough
justifyleft
justifycenter
justifyright
justifyfull
bullist
numlist
outdent
indent
cut
copy
paste
undo
redo
link
unlink
image
cleanup
help
code
hr
removeformat
formatselect
fontselect
fontsizeselect
styleselect
sub
sup
forecolor
backcolor
charmap
visualaid
anchor
newdocument
separator
```

Comment: I don't have the `tiny_mce_confg.php` file in that directory